# "Memory limits" using sw in mips

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

Lets say i have the following command in MIPS:

```
sw $t0, 0($sp) # $sp=-4
```

Does that mean that the register $t0 is saved from 0 to -3 byte or from -4 to -7 byte ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack growing downward in memory to make space for new data to be saved. The stack pointer `$sp` point to the top of stack.

The stack pointer `$sp` starts at a high memory address and decrements to expand as needed. Figure (b) shows the stack expanding
to allow two more data words of temporary storage. To do so, `$sp` decrements by `8` to become `0x7FFFFFF4`. Two additional data words,
`0xAABBCCDD` and `0x11223344`, are temporarily stored on the stack.

So in your case if I understand your question well the `sw` is word- addressable and the word will be stored on that location in memory which `$sp` point to. In case you store the next word it must have an offset of `4`. 
[Harris&Harris]

[image: stack]

**UPDATE**

Take this example when you use `lb`
Say you have this word `0x23456789`

when using `lb $s0,1($0)` After the load byte instruction, `lb $s0, 1($0)`,
`$s0` would contain `0x00000045` on a big-endian system and `0x00000067` on a
little-endian system.[Harris&Harris]

[image: bigendian]

Comment: thanks for your asnwer @adam. So lets say in my example i want to load each byte from my word. Should i say lb $t0, 4($sp) for the first byte, lb $t1, 3($sp) etc OR lb $t0, 0($sp) for the first, lb $t0, -1($sp) for the second etc

Comment: when you use `sw` it means you are storing 4 bytes in one memory cell which is word addressable and pointed by the `$sp`. In case you use `lb` than you are dealing with byte-addressable memory which also depends if it's big endian or little endian.

Comment: yes i know this lets say we are dealing with big endian. and store a word like my example sw $t0, 0($sp) with $sp=-4. if i want to load the first byte of this word into $t1, what should i do?

Comment: use `lb` with offset of `0` and then the next `lb` should have an offset of `1`

Comment: like this  lb $t1, 0($sp) => address+sp=0-4=-4? The next one lb $t2, 1($sp) address+sp=1-4=-3

Comment: yes that is correct but `$sp` still pointing to a 4 byte word address it doesn't matter when use `lb`